# Inequality involving tangent provided $\tan\theta\geq 1$

Tags: trigonometry

If $\tan\theta\geq1$, then
$$\sin\theta-\cos\theta\leq\mu(\cos\theta+\sin\theta)\implies\tan\theta\leq\dfrac{1+\mu}{1-\mu}.$$

Why? I get as far as the obvious $$\tan\theta\leq1+\mu(\cos\theta+\sin\theta)$$

Comment: Is $\mu$ any real number?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume for the moment that we are in quadrant I (i.e., $\sin{\theta} \ge 0$ and $\cos{\theta} \ge 0$).  Then

$$\frac{\sin{\theta}-\cos{\theta}}{\sin{\theta}+\cos{\theta}} \le \mu$$

Divide through up and down by $\cos{\theta}$:

$$\frac{\tan{\theta}-1}{\tan{\theta}+1} \le \mu$$

which means that

$$\tan{\theta}-1 \le \mu (\tan{\theta}+1) \implies (1-\mu) \tan{\theta} \le 1+\mu$$

The result follows.  You then need to show that this also works in quadrant III.

Comment: @Valentina: you're welcome.  I noticed that you asked 6 questions and not accepted any answers.  Just so you know, if you get an answer useful to you, you can accept it by clicking on the checkmark to the left.

Comment: @RonGordon I don't understand your statement that said $\frac{\sin{\theta}-\cos{\theta}}{\sin{\theta}+\cos{\theta}} \le \mu$ . If we assume the equality holds, then we can substitute into the original question and get $\sin \theta - \cos ]theta \le \sin \theta - \cos \theta$ , which is true. But according to your inequality this is the max of the RHS. Shouldn't this be the min, and then your inequality would be $\frac{\sin{\theta}-\cos{\theta}}{\sin{\theta}+\cos{\theta}} \ge \mu$ ?